# FBAnnotationClustering Show Annotation Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm using [FBAnnotationClustering](https://github.com/infinum/FBAnnotationClustering) in  my project. I've hit a wall when coming to display the annotation view programmatically..

eg.
When snapping to a pin on the MapView we'd like to show the annotation.

I've went through the code and can't seem to find where it fires the "show annotation" type function.

The simple answer of `mapView selectAnnotation`  doesn't work since the annotations aren't set with the map and `"ERROR: You are trying to select an annotation that has yet been added to the map"` appears....

Any ideas?

Comment: hi @Mark, did you came up with a solution?

Comment: @QuentinMalgaud I was provided a solution by the developer. I'll submit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Developer of FBAnnotationClustering replied to my issue on GitHub with the following answer.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[FBAnnotationCluster class]]) {
        FBAnnotationCluster *cluster = (FBAnnotationCluster *)view.annotation;

        int i = 0;
        MKMapPoint points[cluster.annotations.count];

        for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in cluster.annotations){
            points[i++] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        }

        MKPolygon *polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:i];
        MKMapRect newMapRect = [polygon boundingMapRect];

        [mapView setVisibleMapRect:newMapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The GitHub issue is over [here](https://github.com/infinum/FBAnnotationClustering/issues/23)